# Python SIP library

Tags: python, voip, sip, trixbox

I need to write python application connect to trixbox that run as SIP server. But I not found any library that implement in python. I found SIP SKD at http://www.vaxvoip.com/ but it not support python. Can anyone suggest me an alternative to VaxVoip?
Thank you.

Comment: You are lucky they don't have a python integration. Their software is horrible and their support is even worst.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are [Python bindings](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Python_SIP_Tutorial) for the PJSUA API.

Comment: +1 typo in url. correct one: http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Python_SIP_Tutorial

Comment: There is no precompile package make me waste much time, I can't made it work on Windows but on Linux it so easy.

Comment: Note PJSUA is GPL, which makes it difficult to integrate in many commercial projects.

Comment: Just came to this answer and the comment from @jjmontes is somehow surprising: it is super-easy. Contact the PJSIP team (I have no affiliation) and negotiate a commercial license. No, I haven't done it, but I have seen such a commercial license.

Comment: * IMPORTANT! :* Python module for PJSIP has been deprecated and although it may still be usable, the module, as well as this doc page, will no longer be maintained. For the replacement, please use PJSUA2 and Python SWIG binding as described

Answer (score 15):

[Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) supports SIP. That's really cool

Comment: Note that Twisted's SIP implementation is somewhat dated, it's still compliant with the old RFC (2543).

Comment: They are trying to update it to RFC 3261 according to http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/SIPPlan but it is not a high priority, see http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/3584

Comment: @LB40 can you give me a sipmle example of using twisted sip protocol?

Answer (score 10):

You might want to have a look at [Sippy](https://github.com/sippy/b2bua).  It's a B2BUA with a complete SIP stack implementation underneath (you could use just that).  It's written entirely in Python, so it's pretty hackable.  Sippy is implemented with Twisted but uses none of its SIP functionality.

Comment: The link you gave is a site that says `Hello World` at the root.