# VoIP in Python then http

Tags: php, python, voip, voice

Hello there
i wanted to know if it was possible to make a voip script in python and then if it works integrate it online on my web site
thanks a bunch

Comment: What do you mean by "make a voip script"? What do you mean by "integrate it"?

Comment: is there a script that i can run and be able to make PC - Land calls. And be able to upload it so my server so i can implement it in my site.

Comment: It takes some understanding of TCP/UDP transport, SIP, H.323 to implement what you're planning. Web site integration is not a trivial task.

Comment: The solution to this isn't copy-and-paste. You'll find that quality StackOverflow answers pop up on questions with a solvable goal instead of an open-ended request for guidance. You'll consider this snark, but: if you have to ask this question, you're not ready to admin this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are very vague if you ask me.

I guess it is possible because there are [SIP libraries in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286875/python-sip-library).