# how can I make a sip call with twisted sip protocol?

Tags: python, twisted, sip, asterisk

I have an asterisk server and I want to  know is this possible to make a sip call with twisted sip protocol? if yes how can I do this?
unfortunatly I can't find any document about how to use twisted sip protocol or any example of  how It works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Slightly odd request, but yes, it's possible.

For some examples of how to being a SIP session with a server, see the [Twisted SIP Test Cases](https://github.com/racker/python-twisted-core/blob/master/twisted/test/test_sip.py). Once the SIP session is established, you'll need to UDP blast your audio packets over.

Long story short, this will be mostly a manual job, with lots of code. However, it's very interesting! Be sure to post it on github when you have it working.

Then again, most of the heavy lifting is [already bundled into some other libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286875/python-sip-library), so using twisted's SIP modules may not be the best case here. Instead, you could wrap external calls in a twisted reactor, and still feel cool!

Comment: I tried other library like this : 'sipsimpleclient.org' and I have no problem with It,but I want to write a voip apllication for android and I have some problem with running other library on android.twisted work fine on android so I like to work with It.  do you know any better library that works on android?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not familiar enough with Android development to answer that.

Comment: @nim4n if you have done that by now can you please share gist link or github repo link where sip handling is done ?