# how to writing SIP client in python

Tags: python, client, sip, voip

I need to add some SIP based functionality to my company's python based software, to receive calls from SIP soft phones. Our python app will receive the call and get the audio stream and sent to our transcription engine.

I'm wondering if others have done this sort of thing and if so do you have any recommendations on how to get started.

Should I write my own SIP stack from scratch?

Should I consider other 3rd party libraries?

Comment: Don't write your own SIP stack from scratch. SIP  base mechanisms are based on [rfc3261](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3261), which has 269 pages. Try to find 3rd party python lib!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python SIP library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286875/python-sip-library)

Answer (score 2):

I have done a university project on forwarding Landline calls to android thorough VoIP (From Raspberry Pi). I have used python code and used Twinkle sip client. Twinkle can operate in terminal and GUI.

```
sudo apt-get install twinkle
```

Same time GUI and CLI version will be installed. To run it from terminal twinkle -c. First run GUI version and configure sip account. Then you can control Twinkle from python by python library subprocess.
I have used following link for reference. Check steve's answer in below link
[SIP-Client for Raspberry Pi that works from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435648/sip-client-for-raspberry-pi-that-works-from-command-line)

There are windows version of command line sip clients also available